# How to minimize space between Columns in amCharts Column Chart?

Tags: amcharts

chart.columnSpacing property doesn't work for Simple Column chart. I need to minimize space between two Columns.

How to minimize space between Columns in Simple Column Chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try adding...

```
"columnWidth": [number between 0 to 1]
```

to make the gaps between the columns change.  Adding a value of 1 will make them as wide as possible and touching each other, whereas a value of 0 will make them show as just a line going up.

See example... http://jsfiddle.net/cxypjubz/1/

Comment: Thanks Simon for detailed example. Combination of columnWidth and tweaking CSS code did the trick!